# Proper SQL to Laravel ORM

Tags: php, laravel

I am newbie on Laravel, I have a proper SQL Statement (which works on PHPMyAdmin and Navicat) and I can get results. What i want to do is, I want to take that statements in Laravel without using DB::raw();.

Any Helps will be appreciated.

```
    Select 
        rmm.message,
        count(rmm.message) as number, 
        receivedTime as time

    FROM
           rcs rcs, rmm rmm
    WHERE
          rmm.smsCid =  rcs.smsCid AND  rmm.receivedTime LIKE '%2013-04-01%' AND length('rmm.message') > '3'

    GROUP BY(rmm.message)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively you can use the [Fluent Query Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/database/fluent#where). Here's my attempt, of course it's not checked as I don't have your data structure to hand. Hopefully  enough to get you started:

```
DB::table('rcs') // SELECT FROM rcs
    ->join('rmm', 'rmm.smsCid', '=', 'rcs.smsCid') // Simple INNER join
    ->where('rmm.receivedTime', 'LIKE', '%2013-04-01%')
    ->where(DB::raw('LENGTH(rmm.message)'), '>', 3)
    ->get(array(DB::raw('COUNT(rmm.message)'), 'rmm.message', 'receivedTime')); // Get only the columns you want
```

Comment: You have to put your RAW Sql in `DB::raw()`.
`->where(DB::raw('length(rmm.message)'), '>', 3)`

Comment: Thank you for your assist, but i would like to use  short alias , AS in my sql, which Fluent Query Builder does not support it ? Laravel really makes things hard after  coming from Codeigniter...

Comment: Is there any ->from syntax for Query Library , or I am just making some mistake ??

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DB::query()`](http://laravel.com/docs/database/raw) to run your query. This calls the query method on the active DB [connection](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Laravel.Database.Connection.html#169).

Comment: DB::query() does not give AS and Count alias Sql for view part or I don't know because there is not enough documentation for Laravel ....

Comment: @OnderOZCAN I'm not sure what you mean, because I've used AS aliases successfully with DB::query(). Also, Laravel has API documentation: http://laravel.com/api